# How to implement Rust struct and methods as Vec from C without leaking memory?

Tags: c, struct, binding, rust, ffi

I'm writing Rust [bindings](http://gitlab.com/saruman9/rust-understand) for a C library which uses an embedded constructor and destructor. Raw Rust code of C header:

```rust
// Opaque structures transform to enumerate
pub enum UdbEntity_ {}
pub enum UdbReference_ {}
...
pub type UdbEntity    = *mut UdbEntity_;
pub type UdbReference = *mut UdbReference_;
...

// Return a non-allocated, permanent list of all entities. This list may be
// used in places where an allocated entity list is required and may be
// safely passed to udbListEntityFree().
pub fn udbListEntity(list: *mut *mut UdbEntity, items: *mut c_int);

// Free an allocated list of entities.
pub fn udbListEntityFree(list: *mut UdbEntity);
...

// Return an allocated list of all references for entity.
// Free the list with udbListReferenceFree().
pub fn udbListReference(entity : UdbEntity,
                        refs   : *mut *mut UdbReference,
                        items  : *mut c_int);

// Free the allocated references list.
pub fn udbListReferenceFree(refs: *mut UdbReference);
```

This is implementation of safe Rust code as in [git2-rs](https://github.com/alexcrichton/git2-rs/):

```rust
/// Structure of Entity.
pub struct Entity<'ents> {
    raw: UdbEntity,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'ents UdbEntity>,
}

/// Opaque structure of list of entities.
pub struct ListEntity<'db> {
    raw: *mut UdbEntity,
    len: usize,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'db Db>,
}

/// An iterator over the Entity in list of entities.
pub struct EntityIter<'ents> {
    range: Range<usize>,
    ents: &'ents ListEntity<'ents>,
}

impl<'db> Drop for ListEntity<'db> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { udbListEntityFree(self.raw) };
    }
}
```

And for `ListReference` and `Reference` too.

I need to work with `ListEntity` as with `Vec<Entity>` (iterators, slices for sorting and etc.), but I can't implement it. In my versions of implementing I can't create slices: `from_raw_parts` returns slices over `UdbEntity`, not `Entity`.

When I keep `Vec<Entity>` in `EntityList` and later when I edit `Vec<Entity>` (moving it), `EntityList` is dropped and frees the allocated list `*mut UdbEntity`. I need correct lifetimes too.

I reversed some simple structs (`Kind`, `ListKind` for example) for writing pure Rust code, but I think a more idiomatic path exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two rather disjoint structures in your code. On the one hand, you have a `ListEntity` which owns a raw array of `UdbEntity` and frees it when required, on the other hand you have an `Entity` which wraps the `UdbEntity`, but is not in any way referenced in `ListEntity`.

You have two options here.

1. Transmute an array of `UdbEntity` into an array of `Entity`, in which case you will be able to create slices of it. To do that, they need to have the same in-memory representation.
2. Create a vector of `Entity` separately from `UdbEntity` and return them instead.

Assuming the first approach is safe, I would go with that. If not, then the second one can work. In both cases arrays of `Entity` should be owned by `ListEntity`so that the memory is properly managed. I would probably ditch the `PhantomData` in `Entity` and simply return references to them.

Comment: I liked the first version, so I have not tried. What about the second version - if Vec<Entity> would be owned by ListEntity then ever modification of Vec will cause of dropping ListEntity.

Comment: @saruman9 If the `Vec` is owned by `ListEntity` and visible outside by a reference, then `Vec` can't outlive it - that's guaranteed by Rust. If you need the `Vec` to be mutable, then I'd rather not use it at all, but implement the necessary traits on `ListEntity` itself. The problem here is that the `Vec` and the underlying structures would need to be modified in sync, which is quite difficult to do.

Comment: I implement transmute in `Deref` trait from array `UdbEntity` to `Entity` (with `PhantomData`, because keep simple reference of `Entity` is hard for work with some FFI functions). With `ListEntity` this work now. I will try implement `ListReference` too.